# Jquery: How to make one array of objects from two arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I have two arrays:

```
var last13monthsofData = [0.45, 0.44, 0.46, 0.43, 0.4, 0.41, 0.46, 0.41, 0.4, 0.45, 0.46, 0.46, 0];
var last13monthsofDates = ["11/1/2013", "12/1/2013", "1/1/2014", "2/1/2014", "3/1/2014", "4/1/2014", "5/1/2014", "6/1/2014", "7/1/2014", "8/1/2014", "9/1/2014", "10/1/2014", "11/1/2014"];
```

I'd like to take these two arrays and make one new array of objects with corresponding data and dates:

```
the13monthDataDates=[
{"date":"11/1/2013","data":0.45},
{"date":"12/1/2013","data":0.44},
{"date":"1/1/2014","data":0.46},
{"date":"2/1/2014","data":0.43},
{"date":"3/1/2014","data":0.4},...];
```

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: you explained what you wanted, bit not what your problems were achieving it. Was the expectation to just have someone code this for you? Should really have a problem statement in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
var the13monthDataDates = $.map(last13monthsofData, function(v,k) {
    return {"date": last13monthsofDates[k], "data":v};
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var arr = [];
for (i = 0; i < last13monthsofData.length; i++) { 
    arr.push({ date: last13monthsofDates[i], data: last13monthsofData[i] });
}
```